# Timeline of most recent images on Twitter

Tags: twitter

My eventual aim is to have the user select a trending topic or enter their own, and the most recent images for that trend to appear looking all lovely [like this](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html).

My first obstacle is selecting the images. Using [this API](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/targets/twitter), I've managed to whittle it down to tweets of a given hashtag with images *in them*, like so:

```
twitter.text CONTAINS "sammich" AND
links.domain IN "twitpic.com, yfrog.com, flickr.com"
```

The problem is being able to select and print the images themselves.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So you'd be compiling that filter you've built and running it through their REST stream endpoint, which provides a stream of tweets that match that filter?

It doesn't look like [their stream API](http://dev.datasift.com/docs/rest-api/stream) provides URLs of the media entities themselves, which is strange because twitter's own API does: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities - I'd reach out to Datasift and see if there's an undocumented resource that provides this, or if they plan to add it.

Without that, I'd run a regex on each tweet's returned "text", and extract urls from any of the domains you mentioned. At the point, so long as there's a known pattern between the *link* URL and the image *source* URL (e.g. a twitpic link is http://twitpic.com/a3x0m8, the image source is https://twitpic.com/**show/large**/a3x0m8) you should be able to transform one to the other.